# Выравнивание переменных

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, плагин, sublime-text, jetbrains

Как настроить рефакторинг кода, в частности для переменных, в редакторах sublime и продуктах JetBrains?

Пример JS:

```
var name = 'a',
    secondName = 'b';

var obj = {
   name: 'a',
   secondName: 'b'
}
```

Пример PHP

```
public $name = 'a';
public $secondName = 'b';
```

И после запуска рефакторинга кода:

Пример JS:

```
var name       = 'a',
    secondName = 'b';

var obj = {
   name      : 'a',
   secondName: 'b'
}
```

Пример PHP

```
public $name       = 'a';
public $secondName = 'b';
```

Comment: [Рефакторинг кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Рефакторинг) это принципиально другое, чем расстановка пробелов. То, что вы хотите у *JetBrains* называется Reformat Code. Настраивается: File -> Settings.. -> Editor -> Code Style -> [язык программирования]. Только вот то, что вы хотите, там указать вряд ли получится. Насчет Sublime не знаю

Answer (score 1):

Для IDEA есть немало плагинов, например, [Eclipse Code Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=6546). Кроме того, там есть возможность вызывать внешние утилиты, форматирующие исходники. Вплоть до [отдельного плагина](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1605?pr=idea), который будет подменять внешним форматировщиком встроенный. Так что выбор большой: ищите тот, что умеет нужное и подключайте.

Answer (score 0):

для Sublime есть плагин [Code Alignment](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Code%20Alignment)